# Adding Animation when removing images in jQuery and wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a gallery with favourite images or users where users can remove the images they dont like by clciking on remove. When the images are removed, the next image appears in place of the removed image. I would like to add some animation so that it appears as though the next image slides in.

I am using the following code that displays and removes the images form the page.

```
setTimeout(function(){ g(".justified-image-grid").css({opacity:1}); },500);
}
g(document).ready(function(){
fillFav();
g(".fav_icon").live('click',function(){
var id2 = g(this).attr("id");
if(id2 == 2) {   
var url = window.location.href;
var data = g(this).attr('data');
var itemtoRemove = data;
imgs.splice(g.inArray(itemtoRemove, imgs),1);
var th = g(this); th.addClass("proce");
th.parent(".jig-imageContainer").css({'opacity':.6});
g.ajax({url:url,method:'GET',data:{'did':data}}).done(function(data){
th.attr("id","1"); th.parent(".jig-imageContainer").remove(); th.html(data); });
}

});

g("#jig1-filterButtons").live('click',function(){
 g(".justified-image-grid").css({opacity:0});
 setTimeout(function(){ fillFav(); },100);
});
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try This.

**For Fade Out and remove**:

```
th.parent(".jig-imageContainer").hide('slow', function(){ th.parent(".jig-imageContainer").remove() });
```

**For Fade IN and Adding HTML:**

Add `display:none` style to html that you are appending. And then try this:

```
th.html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```